# Setting up Ghost on Subdomain with Hidden Port - Windows Server 2008 with Apache

Tags: html, apache, port, vhosts, ghost-blog

Before I start, I should say I am running XAMPP on Windows Server 2008 R2. I have `node.exe` allowed through my firewall, as well as `port 2368`. I have also been following the instructions [here](http://www.howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-host-ghost-on-an-apache-subdomain/) with no success.

I have my Ghost installed [here.](http://blog.theobearman.com:2368/)

As you can see, Ghost is only loading with the port as part of the web address.

If you try and load the site without the port [like so](http://blog.theobearman.com/), you get an `Internal Server` error.

My vHosts file for Ghost is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName blog.theobearman.com
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:2368/
</VirtualHost>
```

My config.js file is [here.](http://pastebin.com/2Ab0DrYi) Please note that `198.37.105.108` in the config file is the IP of my server.

Error logs for the `Internal Server` error are as follows:

`[Fri May 15 17:56:25.495296 2015] [proxy:warn] [pid 56352:tid 1580] [client 86.147.117.154:58787] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html.var. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule., referer: http://blog.theobearman.com/`

I would appreciate it if somone could tell me what I need to do so that when you navigate to "http://blog.theobearman.com", Ghost will load without the need for the port as part of the web address.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to enable the proxy module for Apache:

```
# Enable the modules.
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy

# Restart Apache
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: @aliacoa I have enabled those modules already. Apologies for not putting it in the opening post.